# Getting a matrix size error even though the size is correct

Tags: matlab, matrix, size

Can anyone help me with a problem I have. I have 4 columns of variables x, y, u and v.

I am using the following code to map these results onto a contour plot

```
crossflow = xlsread(filename, 'sheet3'); 
x = crossflow(2:1559,1);
y = crossflow(2:1559,2);
u = crossflow(2:1559,3);
v = crossflow(2:1559,4);
quiver(x,y,u,v)
```

but I get the error

```
 Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in VorticityCode066D (line 38)
x = crossflow(2:1559,1);
```

My problem is that x, y, u and v are all 38x41 matrix which is the correct size. Why am I getting this error? Regards, Jer

The `whos` from the comments:

```
Name      Size    Bytes  Class 
U         38x41   12464  double 
V         38x41   12464  double 
cav       38x41   12464  double 
crossflow 1558x50 623200 double
y         38x41   12464  double 
z         38x41   12464  double
```

Comment: can you show the output of 'whos' right after the call to xlsread?

Comment: here is the output `  Name                 Size              Bytes  Class     Attributes

  U                   38x41              12464  double              
  V                   38x41              12464  double              
  cav                 38x41              12464  double              
  crossflow         1558x50             623200  double

Comment: `  Name                 Size              Bytes  Class     Attributes

  curlx               38x41              12464  double              
  data              1520x46             559360  double              
  figureHandle         1x1                   8  double              
  filename             1x122               244  char                
  hd                   1x1                   8  double              
  vorticity           38x41              12464  double              
  x                   38x41              12464  double              
               
`

Comment: `  Name                 Size              Bytes  Class     Attributes
             
  y                   38x41              12464  double              
  z                   38x41              12464  double`

Comment: Sorry I had to spit it up but a comment can only have so many characters. As you can see all the matrices have the size 38x41

Comment: That's why you add stuff like that to the original question instead of putting it in comments. And the size of `crossflow` is the one that's causing you problems.

Comment: May be your `x` is [38x41] just **before** the line which error but that would be irrelevant anyway because it is going to be overwritten. If the line didn't error (=if `crossflow` was at least [1559x4]), then your next `x`, `y`, `z`, and `u` would all be overwritten and become [1558x1] vectors. As @beaker said, the error comes from the size of `crossflow` [1558x50]. It has only 1558 lines but you are asking to return the line 1559 => that throws an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the error message.  On the line

```
x = crossflow(2:1559,1);
```

You're getting the error "index exceeds matrix dimensions" because your index (you're asking for the 1559th row among others) exceeds the dimensions (1558 rows available according to the `whos` output) of your matrix (`crossflow`).

Remember that indexing in Matlab is 1-based (unlike most programming languages) so the first and last rows of a 1558-row matrix have indices 1 and 1558, respectively.   Also, ranges like `2:1559` are *inclusive* at both ends (unlike Python, in case you're familiar with that).

As a side note, you can use the token `end` as an index.  If you *really* mean "take the whole first column **except** the first row" you can say `crossflow(2:end, 1)`.  That saves you hard-coding the size of today's `crossflow` into a script that may need to be used tomorrow.